# Segulah to Heal Jaundice Baby for Bris

Tags: brit-milah, netilat-yadayim-washing, segulah

[This site](https://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/164_176_78.pdf) quotes the Steipler saying that it is a segulah to wash a baby's hands (like "negel vasser" when a person wakes up) if it has jaundice that may delay the bris milah. Is this segulah written in any seforim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Steipler is quoted in the first volume of Orchos Rabbeinu (page 289) under Segulah 4 saying to wash the infant's hands each morning after it wakes up to remove jaundice before a bris.

> שמעתי בשם רצ"כ (שיחי') ז"ל ומעוד כמה ששאלו את מו"ר (שליט"א) זצוק"ל
> אודות תנוקות שנהיו צהובים לאחר לידתם לפני הברית ואמר מו"ר שיטלו את
> ידיהם של התינוקות כל בוקר לאחר שינה (נעגעל ואסער) וכך עשו וסרה הצהיבות
> ועשו את הברית בזמנו (ושמעתי שגם לילדות הנולדות שנעשות צהובות שנוטלים
> להן ידיהן מועיל הדבר). א"ה, אני בעצמי לא שמעתי ממו"ר את הסגולה הנ"ל אף
> ששאלתי אותו כמה פעמים אודות תנוקות שנהיו צהובים לאחר לידתם לא אמר לי
> כנ"ל